# Chartist.js multiple line chart different Highs and Lows

Tags: angular, chartist.js

The problem I am having with Chartist.js is that when I'm trying to plot a chart with two different series, I can only seem to specify the highs/lows for the whole chart and not separately for the two different lines(series). 
One of my series has values from [0,1] while the other has bigger values, even in the thousands.. I would like plot both of them togheter with their highs and lows.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I normalized the data to 0-1 range with the help of this post and it worked like a charm:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70801/how-to-normalize-data-to-0-1-range